# Delayed Job Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a same task that i want to run twice - one after 30min, one after 120 min.

I am writing it this way now, but i am sure there is a better way around it

```
  def postpone_30_min
    // same task
  end
  handle_asynchronously :postpone_30_min, :run_at => Proc.new { 30.minutes.from_now }


  def postpone_120_min
    // same task
  end
  handle_asynchronously :postpone_120_min, :run_at => Proc.new { 1200.minutes.from_now }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (assuming you are using the latest version of DJ):

```
class Foo
  after_create :schedule_reminder    

  def send_reminder
  end

private:

  def schedule_reminder
    delay(:run_at => 30.minutes.from_now).send_reminder
    delay(:run_at => 2.hours.from_now).send_reminder
  end    
end
```

Comment: do you know how to do it with the handle_asyn...  line?